# Bluetooth device not visible on iOS but visible on MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos, bluetooth

I'm trying to discover a bluetooth device from an iOS app I developed. The device is an industrial sensor which send a measure every x ms.

I dont understand why I can see and connect to the device from my MacBook but not from my iPhone. The device is not visible in iPhone bluetooth settings. I dont find it through CoreBluetooth too (by using 'scanForPeripheral' method). Is there particular specifications on iOS?

I'm allowed to setup every data I want on the BT device (profil, CoD, UUID, etc.)

The iOS app is basic and simple. I'm using CoreBluetooth framework.

Comment: Csn you see the device with [nRF Connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nrf-connect/id1054362403) from the iPhone?

Comment: what iphone are you using? Have you done these tests on an actual device? Do not use the simulator to test

Comment: @Codo Sadly no...

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Im using my own iPhone XS Max, not the Xcode simulator

Comment: this may sound silly, but try shutting down your phone and restarting the bluetooth on your device... lol ... "have you tried turning it off and on again?" - IT Crowd

Comment: It sounds as if your Bluetooth device is a Bluetooth Classic device (instead of Bluetooth LE aka BLE). iOS support for Bluetooth Classic is very limited (and didn't exist at all before iOS 13). nRF Connect won't show Bluetooth Classic devices as Nordic Semi - to the best of my knowledge - has never been in the Bluetooth Classic business. Check out [What's New in Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901/) and read up regarding *BR/EDR (“Classic”) Devices*. There is a small change it will work with iOS too.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I tried on another iPhone, dont work as well..

Comment: @Codo youre probably right, so MacOS can and iOS cant?

Comment: Yes. Apple considers Bluetooth Classic to be power hungry (and compared to BLE it is). So they think it's ok for a desktop OS but not for a mobile OS. At least that was the original thinking...

Comment: I just setup the HID (Human Interface Device) profil on the bluetooth device and I found it through the Apple bluetooth settings but not on nRF Connect. HID profil has been made for device like keyboard, mouse, etc. It wont help me to transfer data I think...